# THREE.js: how to code for a set of cylinder mesh objects with rapidly changing lengths (+ positions + orientations + colors)

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, geometry

I would like to re-compute and display at least 100 cylinders at 30+ frames per second in a THREE.js animation.

Method 1

Elsewhere (e.g. WestLangley, Mr.Doob) it is recommended to create a pool of mesh objects at Initialisation stage and then re-use them during Animation.
I think this would be feasible if cylinder geometries were unchanged across animation frames.
But my cylinders need to change in length from frame to frame.
I think that Scale cannot be used because the objects are not all aligned to one of the principal axes (x, y or z).

Method 2

Create 100 NEW mesh objects every frame.
But this will lead to rapid memory drain unless they are also deleted after rendering each frame...e.g.

```
    for (var iii=1; iii<=10; iii++)
    {    


    if (MyCylinders[iii])     scene.remove (MyCylinders[iii]);

    // cylinder
    // API: THREE.CylinderGeometry(bottomRadius, topRadius, height, segmentsRadius, segmentsHeight)
        cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 2, 500 * Math.random(), 100, 100, false), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: '#880066'}));
        cylinder.overdraw = true;
        cylinder.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5 * Math.random();
        cylinder.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5 * Math.random();
        cylinder.rotation.z = Math.PI * 0.5 * Math.random();
        cylinder.position.x = 200*Math.random();
        cylinder.position.y = 200* Math.random();
        cylinder.position.z = -200* Math.random();

    MyCylinders[iii] = cylinder;
    scene.add(MyCylinders[iii]);
    }
```

I guess that such frequent creating and deleting will slow the frame rate too much
...as shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/errp5/5/ which struggles to reach 10fps with only 10 cylinders.

My Question

Is there a better way to do this?

ANSWER

Method 1 is the better way (Pool of re-usable mesh objects) when combined with appropriate use of Scale (as suggested by mrdoob) and Rotation.
Working demo at:- http://jsfiddle.net/KjxZp/2/

Key section of code:-

```
var desired_cylinder_length = 195 + 5 * Math.random();
      //... Loop
      for (var iii = 1; iii <= Num_Rays; iii++) {
          cylinder = MyCylinders[iii];

          //... apply new scale and rotation to cylinder
          cylinder.scale.y = desired_cylinder_length;
          cylinder.overdraw = true;

          cylinder.rotation.x += (0.005) * Math.PI * Math.random();
          cylinder.rotation.y += (0.005) * Math.PI * Math.random();
          cylinder.rotation.z += (0.005) * Math.PI * Math.random();

          MyCylinders[iii] = cylinder;
          MyCylinders[iii].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that Scale cannot be used because the objects are not all aligned to one of the principal axes (x, y or z).

You can fix that.

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, 0.5, 0 ) );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry );
mesh.scale.y = Math.random() * 100;
```

Comment: I see how makeTranslation re-origins the mesh.

Comment: But scaling on only one axis will distort the cylinder.  Scaling by same factor on all three axes is good for stretching/shrinking cylinder but I want cylinder radius to stay the same for all cylinders. Scaling does not solve the need for rotation with preserved radius.  I think.

Comment: Aha, maybe I can rotate pre-used cylinder to re-align length on y-axis then re-scale it along y to desired new length then rotate it into desired new position.

Comment: OK I now understand that Scale can be applied before Rotation.  See http://jsfiddle.net/KjxZp/2/ for demo of working code.

Comment: OK Now I realize that Scale works the same way on the cylinder whatever its rotation...e.g. it works on the object xyz axes not the world xyz axes.  I was misled by an incorrect camera aspect ratio (weak excuse!) Thanks for assist @mrdoob.